# Proof of an inequality with expectation of random variables

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, inequality

I'm solving some exercises and got stuck. The setting:

let $\varepsilon > 0 $ given, and $D(\varepsilon):=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R_+}^2\mid |x-y| \ge \varepsilon\mbox{ and }\min(x,y) \le \frac{1}{\varepsilon}\}$.
Define $ h(x):=\exp{(-x)} $ with domain $ \mathbb{R_+} $.
I've proved, that there's a $ \delta > 0 $ (depending on $\varepsilon $ )

$$ h\left(\frac{x+y}2\right) \le \frac{h(x)+h(y)}2 - \delta 1_{D(\varepsilon)}(x,y).$$

Now how could I use this to show:

$$ E(|h(X)-h(Y)|)\le \varepsilon + 2 h\left(\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\right)+ P((X,Y)\in D(\varepsilon))$$

where $X,Y$ non negative random variables.

I'm very thankful for any help.

Comment: It's clear that I have to use the first Inequality. But I do not see how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too long to be explained in a comment. We write 
\begin{align*}
E[|h(X)-h(Y)|]&=E[|h(X)-h(Y)|\mathbf 1_{|X-Y|<\varepsilon}]+E[|h(X)-h(Y)|\mathbf 1_{|X-Y|\geq \varepsilon}]\\
&=E[|h(X)-h(Y)|\mathbf 1_{|X-Y|<\varepsilon}]+E[|h(X)-h(Y)|\mathbf 1_{|X-Y|\geq \varepsilon}\mathbf 1_{(X,Y)\in D(\varepsilon)}]\\
&+E[|h(X)-h(Y)|\mathbf 1_{|X-Y|\geq \varepsilon}\mathbf 1_{(X,Y)\notin D(\varepsilon)}]\\
&\leq E[|X-Y|\mathbf 1_{|X-Y|<\varepsilon}]+E[|h(X)-h(Y)|\mathbf 1_{|X-Y|\geq \varepsilon}\mathbf 1_{(X,Y)\in D(\varepsilon)}]\\
&+E[|h(X)-h(Y)|\mathbf 1_{\min(X,Y)\geq \frac 1\varepsilon}]\\
&\leq \varepsilon + E[\mathbf 1_{|X-Y|\geq \varepsilon}\mathbf 1_{(X,Y)\in D(\varepsilon)}]+E[(h(X)+h(Y))\mathbf 1_{\min(X,Y)\geq \frac 1\varepsilon}]\\
&\leq \varepsilon+P((X,Y)\in D(\varepsilon))+2E[h(\min(X,Y))\mathbf 1_{\min(X,Y)\geq \frac 1\varepsilon}] \\
&\leq \varepsilon +P((X,Y)\in D(\varepsilon))+2 h\left(\frac 1\varepsilon\right).
\end{align*}
But I don't see how to use the previous question.

Comment: just two small question: why is $ E(|h(X)-h(Y)|1\{|X-Y|\ge \epsilon\}1\{(X,Y)\in D(\epsilon)\}) \le E(1\{|X-Y|\ge \epsilon\}1\{(X,Y)\in D(\epsilon)\})$ and why is $ E(|h(X)-h(Y)|) \le E(|X-Y|) $ ? And in the last line it should be a $ h $ instead of $  g$

Comment: We have $|h(X)-h(Y)|\leq 1$, and $|h(u)-h(v)|=|\int_u^ve^{-t}dt|\leq |u-v|$. It's indeed $h$, I will correct it.

Comment: Ok thanks. But there's still something around I don't get. Why is it true that, $ h(X)+h(Y) \le 2min(h(X),h(Y))$.

Comment: $h$ is decreasing so $h(X)\leq h(\min(X,Y))$. (it's $h(\min)$, not $\min h$)

Comment: decreasing, that's the point! Thanks a lot! and again sorry for my ignorance!